# I created a user model myself, but I get an error in 'ChoiceField'. | PYTHON - DJANGO

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I want to add an option to my user model that the user can choose with the comboBox when registering. Everything is fine on the register page, but I get an error when I make a POST request to register.

When I try to register a user, I get the error "('favorite_music' is an invalid keyword argument for this function)".

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/user/register/
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'favorite_music' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Traceback says,

```
C:\Users\adilc\Desktop\DjangoMusic\Music\user\views.py in register
registeredUser = User(username = username, email = email,favorite_music = favorite_music)
```

forms.py

```
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('full_name','username','email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('full_name','email', 'password', 'active', 'admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label = "Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password Confirmation", widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ["username"]
    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password do not match")
        return password2
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.clean_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label = 'Username')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    favorite_music_choces = (
        ("Trap","Trap"),
        ("Rap","Rap"), 
        ("Pop","Pop"),
        ("Rock","Rock"),
        ("Trip Hop","Trip Hop"),
        ("R&B","R&B"),
        ("Country","Country"),
        ("Jazz","Jazz"),
        ("Chill","Chill"),
        ("House","House"),
        ("Electronic","Electronic"),
        ("Dubstep","Dupstep"),
        ("Dance","Dance"),
        ("EDM","EDM"),
        ("Reggae","Reggae"),
        ("Other","Other"),)

    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password',widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    favorite_music = forms.ChoiceField(required = True,choices = favorite_music_choces, label = "Favorite Music")
    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm")
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        favorite_music = self.cleaned_data.get("favorite_music")
        if password and confirm and password != confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords Does Not Match")
        if email == False:
            raise forms.ValidationError("A Valid Email Address")
        values = {
            "username" : username,
            "password" : password,
            "email" : email,
            "favorite_music":favorite_music,
        }
        return values
```

models.py

```
USERNAME_REGEX = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*$'

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,username, email,full_name,favorite_music=None, password=None, active=True, is_staff = False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must have a password")
        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name = full_name,)
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a fullname")
        user.set_password(password)
        user.staff = is_staff
        user.admin = is_admin
        user.active = active
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self,username,email,full_name,favorite_music=None, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username, email, full_name,favorite_music=favorite_music, password = password,is_admin=True, is_staff=True)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_staffuser(self,email,full_name,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,full_name, password=password,is_staff=True
        )
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    favorite_music_choces = (
        ("Trap","Trap"),
        ("Rap","Rap"), 
        ("Pop","Pop"),
        ("Rock","Rock"),
        ("Trip Hop","Trip Hop"),
        ("R&B","R&B"),
        ("Country","Country"),
        ("Jazz","Jazz"),
        ("Chill","Chill"),
        ("House","House"),
        ("Electronic","Electronic"),
        ("Dubstep","Dupstep"),
        ("Dance","Dance"),
        ("EDM","EDM"),
        ("Reggae","Reggae"),
        ("Other","Other"),)

    username = models.CharField(max_length = 30,
    unique=True,
    verbose_name = "Username",
    validators = [RegexValidator(regex = USERNAME_REGEX,
    message="Username must be alphanumeric or contain numbers",
    code="invalid_username")])
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name = "Email",
    )
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    favorite_music = models.CharField(max_length = 20,choices = favorite_music_choces, verbose_name = "Favorite Music",blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    #timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username" 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email","full_name"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.full_name: 
            return self.full_name 

    def get_short_name(self):
        pass

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return self.admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return self.admin
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        favorite_music = form.cleaned_data.get("favorite_music")

        registeredUser = User(username = username, email = email,favorite_music = favorite_music)
        registeredUser.set_password(password)
        registeredUser.save()
        login(request, registeredUser)
        return redirect("index")
    context = {
            "form" : form
        }
    return render(request,"register.html",context)
```

admin.py

```
User = get_user_model()
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('username','email', 'admin')
    list_filter = ('admin','staff','active','favorite_music')
    fieldsets = (
        ('User info', {'fields': ('username','email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('full_name','favorite_music')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin','staff','active')}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username','email', 'password1', 'password2','active','staff','admin')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email','username','favorite_music','full_name')
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `MyUser` instead of `User`?

Comment: All **MyUser** classes etc. should I use their name instead of **User**? @ResleyRodrigues

Comment: Yes! You need to use your classes to access the fields they have. The class `User` does not have any of the extra fields you have added.

Comment: It worked fine when I deleted the full_name field. Is Django applying a field limit to us? @ResleyRodrigues

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done. Looking at your stack trace, I suggested something that should have worked. Removing `full_name` should not have any effect. If It does, I don't know how it affected it. In general, you cannot pass anything that is not a model field, in the init of the model.

Answer (score 0):

`favorite_music` choices are a tuple. In the database level, the `favorite_music` keep only choice value, not the whole tuple.

If you want to create `User` object with `favorite_music` choice try this.

```
registeredUser = User(username = username, email = email,favorite_music = "Trap")
```

I am using `Trap` just, for example, you can assign any value from `favorite_music` choice tuple.

Comment: Doesn't work. It's give same error.  `registeredUser = User(username = username, email = email,favorite_music = "Trap") `
and actually i did print(type(favorite_music)) and python said to me its string :). So, favorite_music doesn't send a tuple to database.
INPUT;
`print(type(favorite_music))`
OUTPUT;
`<class 'str'>`

Comment: What is the field type in model?

Comment: CharField in model, ChoiceField in forms. and i can register a user in admin panel with a favorite music. But i cant register in /user/register URL  :S